# Scroll the tableview fast to the end of the tableview and like to download only image of visible cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview of 10000 cell and each cell contains text and image url to show.
I would like to scroll tableview very fast to the end of the tableview, and for each row send the async request to downloading the image, it means 10000 downloading thread request calls, but I need to only download the visible cells images not the all scrolled cells image.

I like to optimise only visible cells image request call not all the table.

Comment: Cell for row code is execute only for your visible cell, So when you scroll table request for next cell will be called.

Comment: No,I scrolled very fast till end of the tableview, and each cell is called

Comment: Yes, It will called due to cellForRow, when you scroll from top to bottom every cell very fast, the code inside cellForRow will execute.

Comment: But I don't want to call or download of images of all irrespective only call the the visible rows, if we scroll to the end of tableview ...its unnecessary download all the images of all the cells, and we only needs 5 or 6 images to show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView+AFNetworking third party doing this but we have to be make sure we add associatedKeys in each cell.

Source Given Below.

http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/04/27/fastscroll/

Answer (score 0):

> You can use kingfisher for these.

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher